# How can i add new column to a 2D array in javascript after each iteration?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, 2d, css-tables

I have 2 arrays. (arr1, arr2) I want to take the value at index 0 and
multiply it by each value in arr2, and add each value to a new row in
a 2D array.
ex.

```
arr1 = [1,3,5,7] arr2 = [4,2,1,6]
```

Outcome should be:

```
 2Darray = [
   [4,12,20,28],
   [2,6,10,14],
   [1,3,5,7],
   [6,18,30,42] 
];
```

Im having trouble with the for loop in javascript and how to create a
new row after each iteration. ```

Thanks

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I follow the formula you are trying to use that would result in each of the results in a given row.

Comment: Shouldn't the first entry be `[4,12,20,28]` ?

Comment: If so your description is backwards.  You are not taking the index of array 1 and multiplying it for each array 2.  You are taking each array 2 element and multiplying it with the array 1 elements.

Answer (score 0):

You could map the arrays with the product of the values.

```js
const
    array1 = [1, 3, 5, 7],
    array2 = [4, 2, 1, 6],
    result = array2.map(v => array1.map(w => v * w));

result.map(a => console.log(...a));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using map like others said would be best.

Using the remainder operator(%) makes the most sense in my head:

```
const arr1 = [1,3,5,7];
const arr2 = [4,2,1,6];

var twoDemArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {

  let tempArr = [];
  
  for (var j = 1; j < arr2.length+1; j++) {
    let newNum = arr1[i]*arr2[j-1];

    tempArr.push(newNum);
    
    if (j % arr2.length == 0) {
      twoDemArray.push(tempArr);
      tempArr = [];
    };
  };

};

console.log(twoDemArray)
//do stuff with twoDemArray
```

Answer (score 0):

Mapping over both arrays helps.

```js
arr1 = [1,3,5,7];
arr2 = [4,2,1,6];

let res = arr2.map(a2 => arr1.map(a1 => a1*a2))
console.log(res);
```